# Dubts about PHP Parametized queries and password_hash

Tags: php, mysql

i'm new of PHP. I was using sha-1 to store password in my database and i did only the check between the stored sha-1 and the sha-1 calculated from password that user had inserted. Now i'm trying to use password_hash() and password_verify().

I have a question about my code:

```
  $user = htmlspecialchars($_POST["username"]);
  $passw = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

  if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("
                                SELECT Password
                                FROM Users
                                WHERE Username = ?
                                LIMIT 1
                            ")) {

      $stmt->bind_param("s", $user);

      $stmt->execute();

      $stmt->bind_result($passwDB);

      $stmt->fetch();

      if( password_verify($passwDB,$passw) ){

          if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){
            session_start();
          }

          $_SESSION['login'] = $user;    
      }

      $stmt->close();
  }

    $conn->close();
```

Is this code right? Currently the password in my database (sql) isn't hashed. Are there best practice to follow?

Ps: Is htmlspecialchars() in this case usefull?

Thank you (and sorry for my english!)

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is for escaping output to the browser. Hash all the passwords in your DB and remove the plain text. `sha-1 to store password in my database` and `password in my database (sql) isn't hashed` seem to contradict.

Comment: You've got it the wrong way around: You need to hash the password once and you store that hash in the database. Then you only use `password_verify()` to check the POST value against the database hash. And don't use `htmlspecialchars` unless you want to output a value to html.

Comment: So should I store salted password in the DB, removing password_hash() from php code? Then i get the salted value from DB and I compare it with the password inserted from user with password_verify()? But salted password shouldn't change every time?

Comment: Arguments for password_verify() are the plaintext password entered by the user, then the password hash from the database, not the other way round, and not a hash of the  password entered by the user

Comment: And "No", htmlspecialchars isn't useful here; store the data in the database as it was entered; where appropriate, use htmlspecialchars when displaying the data